# angularjs element attaches to DOM only on first page entry, but not on page refresh/re-entry

Tags: html, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, dom

In my cordova/ionic app, in one page view button opens a modal and an ng-repeat generates the DOM elements. After the ng-repeat attaches all the new DOM elements, then I am cloning a hidden DIV and attaching the cloned DIV to each of the ng-repeat elements. Once the cloned DIVs are attached, qrCodes are generated (via `canvas`) and then the qrCodes are attached to the cloned DIVs.  It all works on first page entry...and while staying on the page, the modal can be closed opened without issue, it continues to work - the original cloned div is removed, a new one is created and a new qrcode is attached.

But if the user leaves the page view and returns, I can see the cloned DIV and qrcode/canvas are being generated, but the cloned DIV is no longer getting attaching to the DOM - and because the cloned DIV is not being attached to the DOM, the qrCode has nothing to attach to and nothing appears to the user.

The Modal HTML:

```
  <div id="ticketCanvas" class="centerDivContents" style="display:none;" ></div>
  <div id="ticketContainer" class="ticketContainer">
    <div ng-repeat="ticket in club.tickets" id="ticketDiv_{{ticket.ticketID}}" class="ticketDisplay">
      <div id="ticketID_{{ticket.ticketID}}" class="centerDivContents" >   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This code clones the hidden "ticketCanvas" DIV, updates the ID with a counter value (designed as a cache buster), and the clone DIV is attached to a specific parent element (`ticketID_{{ticket.ticketID}}`) in the DOM.  Then, then qrcode canvas is generated and attached to the newly attached cloned DIV.  It all works the first time page entry, but if the user leaves the page and returns to the page, the cloned DIV no longer attaches to the parent DIV.  Yet in my console output I can see the cloned DIV and the canvas being generated:

```
  //button on main page opens the modal:
  $scope.openTicketModal = function() {
      var tik = $scope.club.tickets[$scope.club.tickets.length-1] ;
      var lastTicket = angular.element("#ticketID_"+tik.ticketID) ;
      $scope.ticketInit = $interval(function() {
        // only generate qrCodes after last modal ng-repeat element has been created
        // this ensures qrCodes aren't trying to be attached before ng-repeat DOM elements are created
        if (lastTicket) {
          $scope.genQRCode() ;
          $interval.cancel($scope.ticketInit) ;
        }
      },100) ;
      $scope.tixModal.show() ;
  } ;



  //$rootScope.tixCounter = 0 ; initialized outside of controller
  $scope.genQRCode = function() {
    $scope.refreshTickets = 1 ;
    clubService.getTickets($scope.club.cID,$scope.club.clID,$scope.club.ceID)
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.refreshTickets = 0 ;
      if (response.success == true) {
        for (var x=0;x<response.tickets.length;x++) {
          var ticket = response.tickets[x] ;
          var tikImgDiv = angular.element('#ticketID_'+ticket.ticketID)[0] ;

          // if a previous clone/canvas was attached, then delete it
          if (tikImgDiv.children.length > 0) {
            console.log("deleteing canvas") ;
            tikImgDiv.removeChild(tikImgDiv.lastChild) ;
          }

          // adding new clone now to parentDIV.
          var tikCanvas = angular.element('#ticketCanvas')[0] ;
          var clone = tikCanvas.cloneNode(true) ;
          clone.id = 'ticketCanvas_' + $rootScope.tixCounter ;
          clone.style.display = "" ;
          angular.element(clone).appendTo(tikImgDiv) ;

          // generate the QR Code and attach canvas to cloned DIV 
          jQuery('#ticketCanvas_' +$rootScope.tixCounter).qrcode({width:150,height:150,text:ticket.liveCode}) ;

          console.log(tikImgDiv) ;  //outputs cloned DIV and qrcode canvas EVERY TIME
          $rootScope.tixCounter++ ;  // cache buster counter
        }
      }
    }) ;
```

What is happening here that won't allow the cloned DIV to be attached to the DOM after the first page entry?

## UPDATE:

On a whim, I moved all of the modal HTML to the main page and did away with the modal.  And now the problem is gone.  So the above issue is specifically related to the modal itself.  Staying on the same page view, opening and closing the modal everything worked.  But leaving the page view and returning, the element would never reattach to the modal again.

At one point I thought this could be related to modal caching, but there seems no way to manage the modal cache.  At least in Ionic v1, there is no method (I am aware of) that allows you to manage the modal cache.